# Quickly append (merge) a PDF document onto 50,000 other documents

Tags: powershell, pdf, cmd, merge, pdftk

We have 50,000 documents monthly that need a single different pdf appended to the end of them.

I have a powershell script that loops through the list of 50,000 and calls PDFtk to merge them. But this is taking many many hours even on a machine with high RAM.

The core of the code is this:

```
foreach ($pdf in $filelist){
  <#Get all variables#>
  ...
  $merge = '"' + $TKPath + '" "' + $FirstPDFPath + '" "' + $SecondPDFPath + '" cat output "' + $OutputPDFPath + '"'
  cmd.exe /c $merge
}
```

Is this an issue with PDFtk? Or am I causing problems by calling `cmd.exe /c` inside the loop? Can I just call PDFtk without that somehow? I've never got it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting 50K `cmd.exe` processes will definitely carry some overhead.

You could attempt to invoke `pdftk` directly from powershell with the `&` call operator:

```
& $TKPath $FirstPDFPath $SecondPDFPath cat output $OutputPDFPath
```

Comment: This sped it up slightly, but it's still opening PDFtk multiple times. Looks like we'll need a new software solution.